type check in react with typescript
In the code below, I specified that setLocale should receive a value of type Locale as a parameter via LocaleContextValue.
But why doesn't the setLocale function throw an error if I don't pass any value as a parameter?
Even if I make it return a string type like () => { return “hello” }, it doesn't throw any error.
import { createContext, ReactNode, useContext, useState } from "react";

type Locale = "ko" | "en";

interface LocaleContextValue {
  locale: Locale;
  setLocale: (value: Locale) => void;
}

const LocaleContext = createContext<LocaleContextValue>({
  locale: "ko",
  setLocale: () => {},
  // setLocale: () => { return "hello"; },
  // No errors occurred.
});


() => {} can perfectly happily accept (and ignore) the value parameter, why did you expect this to be a problem?

You have raised 2 similar points, I'll address each individually:
1. The argument being passed to the function
When you define functions with args in typescript you are saying "when this function is called you HAVE to provide these values..."
So when you call setLocale you HAVE to provide an argument of type Locale, but it doesn't mean you have to use that value inside of the function.
2. Why can I return A string when the definition says return void?
I was surprised this didn't show an error.
Why my surprise: In most explanations of void including on typescripts own site, void can only be of type null || undefined. So I would expect in your definition of setLocale to  get an error when you return a string from the implementation of the function.
However, this shouldn't be too dangerous in the rest of your app because if you try using the value returned by the function in any way other than you would with null | undefined you will get a type error

Thank you for your response.
I was able to find the answer to the second part in the official TypeScript documentation!
I studied Java first, so the typing style in TypeScript feels a bit awkward.
